# Highcharts xaxis label not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with the bar chart, i cant make the label to be shown properly, when the label is too long, it will be cut off[image]

this is what i have for the xAxis property trying to make the label to push the chart on the right when i have long label:

```
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: categories1,                              
                                labels: {                                                                                                                                     
                                    "overflow" : "justify",
                                     "ellipsis": true,
                                     "style": {
                                         "fontFamily": "Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif",
                                         "fontSize": "11px",
                                         "color": "#222222",
                                         "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
                                     },

                                    step: 1    
                                }
                            },
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you replicate your issue as live demo on jsfiddle? In the code, you refer to categories1 array which is not defined.

Comment: @SebastianBochan well it is defined i just copied that part with the xAxis and pasted here

Comment: well I need to have a full code to replicicate it, without that Im not able to debug. Could you prepare live demo?

Comment: @SebastianBochan i think i cant make because i have many variables, anyway thank you for your try

Comment: You can hardcode values or send me categories array and series object only.

Comment: Try to set whiteSpace to 'nowrap'. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3jxkujgf/.